# How much of the hydrogen in our sun will never participate in fusion? What about larger stars?

Tags: stellar-evolution, brown-dwarf, hydrogen, red-dwarf, fusion

From what I gather, only red dwarf stars are fully convective, and will use up pretty much all of their hydrogen....

Is there a chart or list somewhere that shows the percentage of hydrogen that is never fused, for each type of star?  From O-type to M-type?

What about brown dwarfs?  Will they eventually fuse all their hydrogen like a red dwarf, but just take even longer?